# Multiple onCompletion works in Futures in Scala

Tags: scala

While experimenting with Futures in Scala, I notice that multiple calls to OnCompletion works!

**Question 1 - Obviously, I shouldn't write the code this way but I wonder if the compiler should raise an error in this case?**

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Failure,Success}

object ConcurrencyExample extends App {
  val time = System.currentTimeMillis()

  println("looking at inventory")
  //create code we want to execute concurrently
  val f: Future[Int] = Future //or just f = Future
  {
    println("add item to shopping basket")
    Thread.sleep(30) //simulate backend process delay
    println("Item added")
    1 //simulate the no. of items in basket

  }

//this works
  f onComplete (x => println("on complete1 " + x))
//and this too
  f onComplete {
    case Success(value) => println("on complete2 size of basket" + value)
    case Failure(e) => println(e)
  }

//this is called as well though I do not see problem in this as I can segregate the code for completion, success and failure
  f onSuccess {
    case v => println("on success size of basket"+v)
  }

  f onFailure {
    case e => println("on failure. Reason"+e)
  }


  for (i<- 1 to 5)
  {
    println("looking at more items in inventory ")
    Thread.sleep(10)
  }
  Thread.sleep(500)
}
```

//result

```
looking at inventory
add item to shopping basket
looking at more items in inventory 
Item added
on success size of basket1
**on complete2 size of basket1
on complete1 Success(1)**
looking at more items in inventory 
looking at more items in inventory 
looking at more items in inventory 
looking at more items in inventory
```

**Question 2 - Is the order of execution of multiple callback (of same type) deterministic?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Next quote from documentation may answer both your questions:

> The onComplete, onSuccess, and onFailure methods have result type
>   Unit, which means invocations of these methods cannot be chained. Note
>   that this design is intentional, to avoid suggesting that chained
>   invocations may imply an ordering on the execution of the registered
>   callbacks (**callbacks registered on the same future are unordered**).

a1: you can register as many callbacks as you want

a2: they will execute in "random" order.

Comment: I assume that the callbacks are executed in some separate execution context? If I add a sleep in onSuccess (case v => Thread.sleep(2000); println("on success size of basket"+v)), the print will not be executed as the main process will terminate before that.

Comment: yes, they are executed in separate threads, that are taken from defined thread pool (global execution context in your case).